# Azure BlockBlob with SDK V12

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to convert examples of using BlockBlobStorage using the new Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs but I can't find anything within that relating to BlockBlobStorage.

Does this still exist in the new Azure SDK V12?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you’re looking for?

Comment: As far as I knew, in the new Azure storage SDK, the ```BlockBlobStorage```  is  be changed as ```BlockBlobClient```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thanks Jim Xu. That is what I was looking for. I am trying to find a way to stream a zip file into blob storage whilst adding additional files to the zip. We have a lot of files to zip and I need to avoid doing it it memory.

Comment: @GaryF You can do that. You can create zip file first. Then upload the zip file.

Comment: I've just reverted back to the old SDK V12. Unfortunately I can't create the zip file and then upload it as it will take up too much memory hence why I was trying to stream it.

The functionality I need is in the V11 SDK but has not been ported over to V12 yet and it seems that there is no date that this will happen.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8993